# What are the default Yii model scenarios for create and update a record?

Tags: php, yii

While using the Yii active record, for creating and updating is there any default scenario's associated with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default scenario is `insert`, it is defined in constructor of `CActiveRecord` as default param. You can also set scenario as param in class constructor.

When using models from find* methods scenario is set to `update` - thanks [Cédric Belin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084485/cedric-belin).

When model is already instantiated, you can use `setScenario` to set it or `getScenario` to get it.

Comment: The scenario is set to `update` if the models are loaded using `findXXX` methods.